# Centering a table vertically and horizontally, and being able to scroll it

Tags: html, css, fivem

I'm trying to center a table vertically and horizontally, and at the same time be able to scroll it. The code is running inside an embedded Chromium browser in a game, so a Chrome-only solution is accepted.
I tried setting the display to block on the `tbody` but it's not a solution because it makes the content stretch to the left.

My current result:

[image: Scoreboard]

As you can see, the overflow is not handled correctly, while I'd like to get the scrollbar after the set height is reached.

My current code:

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    user-select: none;
}

#wrap {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

th {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}

tr {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

td {
    padding-top: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th, td {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

tr.heading {
    background-color: rgb(117, 0, 0);
    color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.9);
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    
    text-shadow:
      -1px -1px 0 #000,
       0   -1px 0 #000,
       1px -1px 0 #000,
       1px  0   0 #000,
       1px  1px 0 #000,
       0    1px 0 #000,
      -1px  1px 0 #000,
      -1px  0   0 #000;
}

thead {
    width: 100%;
}

tbody {
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

tbody::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}

tbody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(160, 0, 0), rgb(80, 0, 0), rgb(160, 0, 0));
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.col-id {
    width: 15%;
}

.col-name {
    width: 40%;
}

.col-xp {
    width: 15%;
}

.col-level {
    width: 15%;
}

.col-ping {
    width: 15%;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <table id="scoreboard" class="table">
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You can add "overflow-y: auto;" to #wrap

Answer (score 0):

your overflow:hidden shouldn't be related to your body tag but to your table or #wrap